# How do I check if a mail has been sent using MAPI in a WPF-Project?

Tags: c#, wpf, email, outlook, mapi

I am not able to know if the user has sent the mail or aborted the process.

I am working on a WPF-Project that encrypts files in aes-256 and opens an Outlook-popup where you can send the encrypted file. To decrypt the file a Code is needed which is sent by SMS to the Person but if the mail hasn't been sent the SMS shouldn't be sent either. The problem is that I can't find a way to determine it.

```
try
{
    SendMail(zipfile + ".aes");
    if (mapi.sent == true)
        SendNewSms();           //do not send the SMS if the email has not been sent
    else if (mapi.sent == false)
        MessageBox.Show("It didn't work!!");
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: MAIL");
}

public void SendMail(string attachment)
{
    string subject = "";
    string body = "";
    string attachmentPath = attachment;

    mapi.AddAttachment(attachmentPath);
    mapi.SendMailPopup(subject, body);
}
```

The MAPI class has this Code that is supposed to send the Mail. The "sent" variable is a boolean I added myself

```
[DllImport("MAPI32.DLL")]
static extern int MAPISendMail(IntPtr sess, IntPtr hwnd, MapiMessage message, int flg, int rsv);

int SendMail(string strSubject, string strBody, int how)
{
    MapiMessage msg = new MapiMessage();
    msg.subject = strSubject;
    msg.noteText = strBody;

    msg.recips = GetRecipients(out msg.recipCount);
    msg.files = GetAttachments(out msg.fileCount);

    m_lastError = MAPISendMail(new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(0), msg, how,
        0);
    if (m_lastError > 1)
        MessageBox.Show("MAPISendMail failed! " + GetLastError(), "MAPISendMail");

    Cleanup(ref msg);
    return m_lastError;
}
```

My expectation was that the boolean would be set on true if the mail has been sent else it would stay on false.

I hope it's written understandable!

Comment: Hi.
It's unclear what you are programming but i gather from your last paragraph that you are writing a outlook extension ?
Maybe clarify that in the beginning of the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple MAPI doesn't provide any indication of whether a message is sent. However, you may track the Sent Items folder changes. As soon as the item is added to the folder, your message has been sent.

In the Outlook Object Model, you can find the [MailItem.Sent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sent) property which returns a Boolean value that indicates if a message has been sent.